# How can I get this DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date-format, tostring

How can I get this DateTime format using C# - YYYY-MM-DD-HHmmSSSSS

Example: 2014-02-05-151845689

Comment: What should "SSSSS" represent? Seconds and milliseconds?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the last three `S` are the milliseconds:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Why am I getting 00000? even when using cultureinfo

Comment: @MarkFenech: i have no idea, what code have you used? The code above outputs something like `2014-02-05-151537771` as you can see here: http://ideone.com/fX90t6

Comment: DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: @MarkFenech: because you use `DateTime.Today` which "truncates" the time part.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff}",dateTimeVar);
```

or

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmssfff");
```

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: It's also pointless to use a compound string format when the *whole* string format is just formatting one value - call ToString instead.

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error. It's format with a capital 'F' Also, it seems non-canonical.